# Changing HighCharts background color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I don't really know how to do this.

I need to change background color of this highcharts chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/polar-spider/

But I don't seem to be able to do so - there doesn't seem to be any clear place to put the background color setting?

I've tried to write many different values in this section:

```
chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'line'
},
```

But it didn't do anything ( it occasionally broke this script ).

Do I need to change it somewhere in the included .js files? Or can it be done from the level of this loaded script?

JS is really confusing. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The background of the entire chart, or just the section within the hexagon?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Take a look at the Highcharts API here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.backgroundColor and you will see it's a property of the chart object that can take a solid color:

```
{
  chart: {
     backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
     polar: true,
     type: 'line'
  }
}
```

Or Gradiant:

```
{
  chart: {
    backgroundColor: {
       linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
       stops: [
         [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
         [1, 'rgb(200, 200, 255)']
       ]
     },
     polar: true,
     type: 'line'
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried these both for a pie chart but the keeps appearing in the svg anyway, overriding the setting: `<rect x="0" y="0" width="655" height="328" strokeWidth="0" fill="#FFFFFF" class=" highcharts-background"></rect>`

Answer (score 2):

There is a **backgroundColor** tag you can use: (http://jsfiddle.net/aeP4E/)

```
chart: {
      polar: true,
      type: 'line',
      backgroundColor:'blue' 
},
```

Answer (score 1):

That's you want 
`

```
chart: {
            polar: true,
            type: 'line',
            backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
        }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3527r4ty/)

You can   `data: [[0, 0, true],`  you can hide value by '`false`' and you can set your gradient 
by

```
  colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        stops: [
         [0, '#5DBA76'],
        [0.4, '#ffff00'],
        [0.8, '#F30000']
    ],
        minColor: '#ff0000',
        maxColor: '#ffff00'
    },
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can hide value by 'false'

```
data: [[0, 0, false], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 3, 4], [0, 4, 5], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 4], [1, 2, 6], [1, 3, 8], [1, 4, 10], [2, 0, 3], [2, 1, 6], [2, 2, 9], [2, 3, 12], [2, 4, 15], [3, 0, 4], [3, 1, 8], [3, 2,12], [3, 3, 16], [3, 4, 20], [4, 0, 5], [4, 1, 10], [4, 2, 15], [4, 3, 20], [4, 4, 25]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3527r4ty/1/

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?