# How to distinguish Highcharts background color for if statement

Tags: javascript, background, charts, highcharts

I want to change the background color of a Highcharts Highstock chart on pressing a button. If the BG color is white by default, I wanna change it to some gradient filling. Otherwise it should be white. So there should be a switch between two color options basically.

As posted in another thread ([Changing HighCharts background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731153/changing-highcharts-background-color)), I already know how to change the BG color. My problem is to distinguish the actual color in the chart in order to use an if statement.

My code looks like this:

```
var gradient = {
        linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 400],
                 stops: [ [0, 'rgb(96, 96, 96)'], 
                          [1, 'rgb(16, 16, 16)'] ]
        };

if( chart.backgroundColor == 'FFFFFF' )
    {
        console.log('if white');
        chart.chartBackground.attr({
             fill:gradient
        });
    }
else 
    {
    console.log('else');
    chart.chartBackground.attr({
        fill: '000000'
    });
    }
```

In my case there will be always called the else statement. So I think there should be another property than chart.backgroundColor, I also tried chart.chartBackground.

Any idea how to access the background color property of the chart? Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check `chart.chartBackground.fill` value.

http://jsfiddle.net/ewLjj/1/

or `chart.options.chart.backgroundColor`

In both examples, value will be true.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you a lot! For next time, where can I get more information about attributes and values like these?

Comment: You can use console.log(chart) in callback. Then only what you need is run a developers tools (Chrome / FF / IE).