# How to add gradient colors above chart line?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/yaxis-reversed/) I am getting gradient color at top of the chart area by reversing y-Axis. check the image below .

```
   yAxis: {
            reversed: true,
            showFirstLabel: false,
            showLastLabel: true
         }
```

[image]

I don't want to reverse the y-Axis, if i am reversing the y-Axis my chart also reversed. I want the gradient color which is in top of the chart line without using this Reversed Y-axis. Suggest me to if any other options in highcharts.

Could any one help me to solve this.

[image]

I am working live random data. In this case only the area traveled by the data should get the gradient color , empty space other than the data in chat shouldn't get gradient color.

As per @DaMaxContent answer , the output will act like below image.

[image]

I don't want that gradient which filled in other area of the chart data. Could you please help me to resolve this.

Comment: So take a look at the gradient settings they have used, and instead of applying them to the series, apply them to the plotBackgroundColor (example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/plotbackgroundcolor-gradient/ )

Comment: @jlbriggs as mentioned in the duplicate, plotBackgroundColor only affects the main plot. It will not affect the range selector area

Comment: @DaMaxContent I don't see what that has to do with anything. Apply it to the chart.backgroundColor in that case. But that doesn't seem to be what the poster wants anyway - they're asking about restricting the background color to the portion of the plot on which there is data.

Comment: @jlbriggs aesthetics. uniformity. design. I can name many reasons as to why it matters. If I were to design such a graph, I would become very frustrated realizing that there is no way to color the range selector area independently. While you are right explicitly, it is a good idea to think implicitly.

Comment: @DaMaxContent there are many responses to your comment, but the bottom line is this: what you're talking about is not what the OP asked for. In fact, it's exactly the opposite. It also doesn't make anything about my comment wrong: just change which element you apply the style to if you so desire.

Comment: @jlbriggs while true, my point was that it was not a thorough answer. While it did cover the minimal needed to know, what if the amount of data is bigger than the plot area? Also, my answer was provided before the knowledge that the OP was asking for color up until the latest data. (before he added the part after "could anyone help with this?"

Comment: Yes. It was not a complete answer. That's why it was a comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To meet the various criteria you have asked for, I would accomplish this by creating a dummy series to create the gradient effect.

**Example Result:**

[image: example]

In this scenario, you will need to pre-process your data, and you will need to assign a max value for the y axis explicitly.

**Example Code:**

```
var max = 0;
var data1 = [...your data array...];
var data2 = [];
$.each(data1, function(i,point) {
    max = point > max ? point : max;
});
max = Math.ceil(max * 1.1);
$.each(data1, function(i,point) {
    data2.push((max - point));
});
```

You will then need to assign that max value as your `yAxis` `max` proeprty, and you may need to either set `endOnTick: false`, or otherwise account for the max resolving with your tickInterval:

```
yAxis: { 
  max:max,
  endOnTick:false
}
```

Then for your dummy series, define the background color gradient.
We'll also set the `showInLegend` and `enableMouseTracking` properties to `false` so that it doesn't show in the legend or tooltip:

```
  {
    data: data2,
    showInLegend:false,
    enableMouseTracking:false,
    fillColor : {
      linearGradient : {
        x1: 0,
        y1: 1,
        x2: 0,
        y2: 0
      },
      stops : [
        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
      ]
    }
```

**Fiddle Example:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/mcp3trmk/

This ensures that the gradient will always match the data, as requested.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It helps me lot. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

## The break down:

You can use gridZindex and backgroundColor/fillColor properties to produce the desired effect. Only issue is that **the grid *has* to be displayed over graph**.

#### The solution:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qqrqeLge/)**

#### The code behind it:

```
chart: {
  type: 'area',
  backgroundColor: { //<<--that is what you are using as fill color
    linearGradient : {
      x1: 0,
      y1: 1,
      x2: 0,
      y2: 0
    },
    stops : [
      [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
      [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
    ]
  }
},

rangeSelector: {
  selected: 1
},

title: {
  text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
},

yAxis: {
  reversed: false,
  showFirstLabel: false,
  showLastLabel: true,
  gridZIndex: 1000      //<<--grid Z index is used to display grid lines over the graph instead of under it
},

series: [{
  name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
  data: data,
  threshold: null,
  fillColor : "#fff", //<<--fill color under the line to simulate effect
  zIndex: 1000,
  tooltip: {
  valueDecimals: 2
  }
}]
```

If you wish to get rid of the marginal color areas, you can get rid off the graphs margin with `chart: { [... ,] margin: 0 [, ...] }` and then use the `container's` padding as the graph margin.

#### More info:

- **highcharts styling guides:**

  http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/design-and-style
- **grid Z index:**

  http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/highcharts/Example/Axis/Set_grid_line_z_index.htm
- **background color:**

  [Changing HighCharts background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731153/changing-highcharts-background-color)
- **(alternative to bg color) plot background color (bg color of **main plot only*):**

  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.plotBackgroundColor

<sup>*range selector areas will not be affected</sup>

Comment: You made my day. Great answer.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see from [this js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/yaxis-reversed/) you have to add this:

```
series: [{
            name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
            data: data,
            threshold: null,
            fillColor : {
                linearGradient : {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 1,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 0
                },
                stops : [
                    [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                ]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
```

See the [documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors) for further information

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your kind reply.
As you mentioned example, They are using reversed y-axis, if you are not using that option means it the gradient colors are came down.Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tjf3n11u/)
_Ranjith