# How to add gradient colors above of the chart line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, highcharts

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/yaxis-reversed/) I am getting gradient color at top of the chart area by reversing y-Axis. check the image below .

```
   yAxis: {
            reversed: true,
            showFirstLabel: false,
            showLastLabel: true
         }
```

[image]

I don't want to reverse the y-Axis, if i am reversing the y-Axis my chart also reversed. I want the gradient color which is in top of the chart line without using this Reversed Y-axis. Suggest me to if any other options in highcharts.

Could any one help me to solve this.

[image]

I am working live random data. In this case only the area traveled by the data should get the gradient color , empty space other than the data in chat shouldn't get gradient color.

As per @DaMaxContent answer , the output will act like below image.

[image]

I don't want that gradient which filled in other area of the chart data. Could you please help me to resolve this.

Comment: you've asked the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503946/how-to-add-gradient-colors-in-highcharts  just update your existing post if you have additional information to provide

Comment: If you liked this answer, please select it on your original question, because this question will likely be closed

Comment: something like this (except unto edge instead of specific time): http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/plotbands-color/ should do

Comment: @jlbriggs , Sorry i am new to stackoverflow. I have updated in my question here :[stackoverflow.com/questions/35503946/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503946/)

Comment: @ DaMaxContent : I have updated my question in my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The break down:

> You can use gridZindex and backgroundColor/fillColor properties to
>   produce the desired effect. Only issue is that **the grid *has* to be
>   displayed over graph**. Here is the solution: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qqrqeLge/)**

Here is the code behind it:

```
chart: {
  type: 'area',
  backgroundColor: { //<<--that is what you are using as fill color
    linearGradient : {
      x1: 0,
      y1: 1,
      x2: 0,
      y2: 0
    },
    stops : [
      [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
      [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
    ]
  }
},

rangeSelector: {
  selected: 1
},

title: {
  text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
},

yAxis: {
  reversed: false,
  showFirstLabel: false,
  showLastLabel: true,
  gridZIndex: 1000      //<<--grid Z index is used to display grid lines over the graph instead of under it
},

series: [{
  name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
  data: data,
  threshold: null,
  fillColor : "#fff", //<<--fill color under the line to simulate effect
  zIndex: 1000,
  tooltip: {
  valueDecimals: 2
  }
}]
```

If you wish to get rid of the marginal color areas, you can get rid off the graphs margin with `chart: { [... ,] margin: 0 [, ...] }` and then use the `container's` padding as the graph margin.

## more info:

> **highcharts styling guides:**
>
> http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/design-and-style
>
> **grid Z index:**
>
> http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/highcharts/Example/Axis/Set_grid_line_z_index.htm
>
> **background color:**
>
> [Changing HighCharts background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731153/changing-highcharts-background-color)
>
> **(alternative to bg color) plot background color (bg color of *main plot only*)**
>
> http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.plotBackgroundColor

Comment: Why not using `plotBackgroundColor`? Just like @jlbriggs mentioned in the original question (let's treat this one as a duplicate).

Comment: plotBackgroundColor only works on the main plot. It will not work for both.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply. It was very helpful to me. But I am using live random data and also briefly explained in my question , kindly have a look and help me to solve this  .